# How to use people-picker-component in Azure hosted website without any reference with Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, peoplepicker, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm trying to create a people picker component in asp.net framework project hosted through azure web app service. I'm logging in to the application using **Microsoft Identity Platform**. I used `mgt-people-picker` component but the issue I'm facing with it is I've to use `mgt-login` explicitly to log in and search for user in `mgt-people-picker`. I'm using `msal-provider` with single tenant type. Can anybody please help on this how to use `mgt-people-picker` without explicitly logging in and or is there any other solution to use people picker component in azure hosted website which does not have reference to sharepoint people picker ?

**Thank You in advance !!**

Comment: Do you mean that the application is authenticated through your own backend? And looking to connect that with mgt in the front-end to have a people-picker? I am trying to clarifying which provider is appropriate. Also do you think [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is potentially what you are looking for through the graph?

Comment: And maybe [this proxy provider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/master/samples/proxy-provider-asp-net-mvc) is what you needed